# DataSource Password Encryption&Decryption In TomEE

Tags: apache-tomee

How to encrypt DataSource Password encryption& decryption in TomEE and the best production practice followed in the IT industry regarding this.
A DataSource can be declared via XML in the /conf/tomee.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't understand totally, but I find some docs about this, maybe can help you.

- http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-8.0/docs/datasource-password-encryption.html
- https://tomee.apache.org/examples/datasource-ciphered-password.html
- https://yottabrain.org/tomcat/tomee-datasource-password-encryption/

Comment: thanks i am expecting this kind of encryption mentioned in https://yottabrain.org/tomcat/tomee-datasource-password-encryption/ .. hope it works

Comment: great my friend : )